# Remove duplicate data based on postID

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array which is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [postId] => 105
            [postTitle] => Test
            [postNonArray] => Subzero
            [postDesc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [para] => Subzero
                            [align] => L
                        )

                )

            [postDate] => 25.08.2016
            [postTime] => 13:44
            [postImage] => http://testyourprojects.biz/custom/ci/tharjumal/uploads/post/post_1472112857.png
            [postVideo] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [postId] => 106
            [postTitle] => Test 2
            [postNonArray] => Test
            [postDesc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [para] => Test
                            [align] => L
                        )

                )

            [postDate] => 26.08.2016
            [postTime] => 18:08
            [postImage] => http://testyourprojects.biz/custom/ci/tharjumal/uploads/post/post_1472215085.jpg
            [postVideo] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [postId] => 106
            [postTitle] => Test 2
            [postNonArray] => Test
            [postDesc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [para] => Test
                            [align] => L
                        )

                )

            [postDate] => 26.08.2016
            [postTime] => 18:08
            [postImage] => http://testyourprojects.biz/custom/ci/tharjumal/uploads/post/post_1472215085.jpg
            [postVideo] => 
        )

)
```

As you can see, there is two post details with `postId=106;`
How can I remove the redundant data from the array based on `postId`?

The project is on PHP.

Comment: You will need to loop the data and create a new array with unique values. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: this will what you are trting to achieve:-  https://eval.in/630678

Comment: Is redundant defined by just the post id? what if the contents of that post has changed? Which one do you want to delete, the first one, or the last one? Those questions aside, you can loop the array and keep a map of the ids you have seen. on each entry, query the map, and if the entry exists, don't copy the entry to a new array (or whatever your strategy is for selection) else, add the id to the map and add the post to the new data structure. rinse and repeat until the original array has been walked.

Comment: @TravisRodman, basically all the values of the whole array will be duplicate, not just postId.

Comment: @Anant, your answer fit my requirement. I upvoted you immediately after checking it on. However, SO doesn't let anyone accept an answer before 10 mins or so. So I was waiting to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @Saswat  no problem. Thanks for marking and up-vote. Glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:-

```
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
```

Check output(whole code with your original array):- https://eval.in/630678

Note:- It will remove the duplicate values (so whole duplicate array will gone as you asked in comment)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop the data and create a new array with unique values so here you go:

```
$ShowNewArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(!array_key_exists('postId', $ShowNewArray)){
    $ShowNewArray[$value['postId']] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($ShowNewArray);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest loop like the one below. It will go through all the elements from $your_array_name and will make an unique array of id where we will store the postIds. We will also check if there are duplicated in the $unique_ids array, and if so we will remove that duplicate element.

```
$unique_ids = array();
foreach($your_array_name as $key => $value){
  //check if the postId is in the array of the unique ids
  if(!in_array($value['postId'], $unique_ids)()){
    array_push($unique_ids,$value['postId']); //if it is not - push it there
  } else {
    unset($your_array_name($key)); //if it is - remove the whole element from the array
  }
}
```